# copy like columns from one table to another and text from textbox

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables in SQL, table1 and table2, and they share the same names for columns A,B,C,D,E. But lets same table1 also has F,G,H,I,J,K,L and table2 has one called 'statement'. 
What I would like to do is on a button press, copy table1 to table2 similar columns AND take the text from a textbox and save it to table2 statement column.

I have this that I think would work:

```
    INSERT INTO table2 (A,B,C,D,E)
    select (A,B,C,D,E)
    from table1
```

but I need to get the text from the text box in the same query and save that to column 'statement' in table2 as well...any ideas?

Comment: then you need to create a method that would take the textbox text as a param and pass it to the query or stored procedure using the Params.AddWithValues(@Param, "some text Data") this is not a very difficult thing to do.. also I would look at implementing a where clause as well otherwise I guess that we are to imply that you want to insert the records regardless..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to create a stored procedure that accepts the text from your textbox as a parameter and performs the insert as such:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (A,B,C,D,E,Statement)
    select (A,B,C,D,E, @Statement)
    from table1
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do +1.

Comment: I don't have permission to create a stored procedure at the moment

Comment: You could do parameterized dynamic SQL still.